# Rascal Eclipse libraries and plugins exceptions (just after installation) UPDATED

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rascal

I just have installed the latest version of Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers and then I follow all the steps of the installation process to install Rascal. It runs ok because I tried the 1+1 command and I get a result, but I have got this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.RascalNavigator.restoreState(RascalNavigator.java:25)
    at org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.RascalNavigator.createPartControl(RascalNavigator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4650)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4650)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3930)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openPerspective(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openOther(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.execute(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu.runOther(PerspectiveMenu.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu$3.runWithEvent(PerspectiveMenu.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4166)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1489)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4012)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

And the eclipse configuration:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product -keyring /Users/Aleks/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product -keyring /Users/Aleks/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

And then, I have 2 warnings (Problems):

First:

```
Description: The plug-in's classpath library '.' does not have a corresponding source build entry
Resource: build.properties
Path: /assignment2  
Location: line 1    
Type: Plug-in Problem
```

Resource file content: `bin.includes = META-INF/`

Second:

```
Description: The JRE container on the classpath is not a perfect match to the 'JavaSE-1.6' execution environment
Resource: MANIFEST.MF
Path:/assignment2/META-INF
Location:line 8
Type:Plug-in Problem
```

Resource file content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: assignment2
Bundle-SymbolicName: assignment2
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.imp.pdb.values,
 rascal
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

And in my output I have this warning:

```
Could not run Plugin.rsc main of assignment2
|import:///|: Could not import module Plugin: File rascal://Plugin not found.
[Advice](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/ModuleImport/ModuleImport.html)
```

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1G
-Xss32m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

So, I have got 2 questions. First, what can I do to solve the exceptions? And the second one, are this exceptions going to interfere with the normal functioning of Rascal?(I am a student of the TU/e - software evolution course, do I need to solve the exceptions for the assignment?)

Thank you very much!
Alex.

Comment: Can you also explain exactly when you get these exceptions?

Comment: I open Eclipse, I create a new Rascal project, and the exceptions appear. But Rascal executes 1+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to reproduce such an issue, but I am guessing that Eclipse is confused about which JDK to use. You should try setting `ECLIPSE_HOME` to the JDK 7 you have and use the `-vm` option of eclipse to point to the same.

The second exception may be caused by the first, but first let's get this one out of the way.

From your eclipse.ini it seems that you are not using the right JDK. I would change the line after `-vm` to:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

Added note: the latest release of Rascal depends on JDK1.8

Comment: I already did this when I was installing Rascal, I changed the eclipse init file and I set all the requirements that appear in the installation guide of Rascal.

Comment: How about the ECLIPSE_HOME? It would surprise me if that helped because I never had to do such a thing. But who knows..

Comment: Ok, this is going worse :D
I tried to change ECLIPSE_HOME from the preferences in Eclipse but I am not able to modify it. Then I also checked my computer files and I found 3 different JDKs: jdk1.7.0_17, jdk1.7.0_51 and jdk1.6.0!
Should I delete the otherJDKs? 
The default Eclipse path of the JDK is the latest one, but I don't know how to modify ECLIPSE_HOME.
And the funniest part is that I have more exceptions:
Unable to retrieve system properties (2 times)
Failed to retrieve default libraries for /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home (again)
And a warning...

Comment: Hi Alek, could you copy/paste the contents of your eclipse.ini file in your question (properly quoted). Maybe there is a typo or something there?

Comment: I just put the contents of the eclipse.ini file. But, could I use Rascal with those exceptions? I mean, if 1+1 works, the other stuff should also work, right?

Comment: Sure you can use Rascal. It might not work if you want to generate your own parser, since that needs a working Java compiler. You probably don't need that to do your job.

Comment: Anyway, I think the eclipse.ini file should be adapted. See above in new version of the answer.

Comment: I changed it and now I have got more exceptions. I returned to the previous ini file but they are still there. Rascal is still working but now I have ´Could not run Plugin.rsc main of RascalProject´ in the output, I have two warnings in Problems and new exceptions refering to some plug-ins. And I cannot edit the question because is too long. I will try to download everything again.

Comment: You can ignore the "Could not run Plugin.rsc" warning. if you have new errors, throw away the old errors in the question. downloading a fresh instance of eclipse is always a good idea. also try if switching to the `unstable` update site makes a difference. good luck!

Comment: Seems to me you should indeed ignore the errors and start working on what you want to use the IDE for. Please feel free to ask more questions if you think you are getting stuck on the error messages anyway.

Comment: I think I solved the other exceptions(the question is updated). I tried to create a new project in my desktop and I only got one exception and two warnings.
The only difference between the new project and the old one was the path to the workspace. I think it doesn't like long paths or white spaces in the path or strange symbols like `º`. So now I am working on the desktop and without strange symbols in the path :D @jurgenv @DavyLandman

Comment: very strange, we thought we had solved all the strange path issues, never tried with `º` alike symbols though..

Comment: This was my path:
`/Users/Aleks/Documents/Escritorio/UCM/Ingenieria Informatica/6º year/Estudios/Semester B/Quartile 3/Software Evolution/Assignment 2´ So maybe is not your fault, maybe is because of Eclipse or the JDK. But I think that was the only difference between the two projects because I only was trying to create a new one and try 1+1. Should I leave that exception and warnings and keep working with Rascal? @jurgenv @DavyLandman

Comment: thanks for that info Alek! We will have a look at our path stuff once again :-)